# How to add Ease-in-out effect with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Well, I'm new at javascript, I'm learning. Now I want to add an effect of ease in this code..how do I do that?

```
let slideIndex = 0;

const showSlides = () => {
    const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");

    for(let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    slideIndex++;

    if(slideIndex > slides.length){
    slideIndex = 1;
    }

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(showSlides,3000);
};

showSlides();
```

Comment: Use a library for animations for now. Come back to it when you have more experience. Doing smooth performant cross-browser animations is not trivial if you're new to coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using css:

```
.slide {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
```

For more information check: [MDN - Using CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

And then instead of switching display, you switch opacity:

```
slides[i].style.opacity = 0; // hide

slides[i].style.opacity = 1; // show
```